# grep using array values and make it faster

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep, array

array[1] is a string pulled from a 30k lines CSV:
example:

```
samsung black 2014
```

I need match those lines with one of the values contained within an array (arrayItems).

arrayItems contains 221 values like:

```
apple
sony
samsung
```

The actual script:

```
while IFS=$';' read -r -a array
do
    mapfile -t arrayItems < $itemsFile
    ## now loop through the above array
    for itemToFind in "${arrayItems[@]}"
    do
       itemFound=""
       itemFound="$(echo ${array[1]} | grep -o '^$itemToFind')"
       if [ -n "$itemFound" ] 
       then 
          echo $itemFound 
          # so end to search in case the item is found
          break
       fi
    done
   # here I do something with ${array[2]}, ${array[4]} line by line and so on, 
   # so I can't match the whole file $file_in at once but online line by line.
done < $file_in
```

The problem is that grep don't match.

but works If I try to hardcode $itemToFind like this:

```
itemFound="$(echo ${array[1]} | grep -o '^samsung')"
```

Another thing is... how to do it faster as $file_in is a 30k lines CSV?

Comment: If you want better answers, you need to provide a [better example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You would also benefit from reading Raymond's [smart question essay](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)

Comment: @Thor you're right. next time I will take a little more time and write a smarter question

Comment: Can you provide an example of lines from the CSV file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use grep with file pattern option (-f)

Example:

```
$ echo -e "apple\nsony\nsamsung" > file_pattern
$ grep -f file_pattern your.csv
```

EDIT:
In response of your new contraints:

```
sed 's/^/\^/g' $itemsFile > /tmp/pattern_file
while IFS=$';' read -r -a array
do
    echo ${array[1]} | grep -q -f /tmp/pattern_file.txt
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then 
        # here I do something with ${array[2]}, ${array[4]} line by line and so on, 
        # so I can't match the whole file $file_in at once but online line by line.
    fi
done < $file_in
```

Comment: I think you miss the `-e` option for echo

Comment: I need to check it line by line. (question code updated)

Comment: Yes, this is working very fast! I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19380925/grep-a-large-list-against-a-large-file) too. Now the only thing I miss is the `^` in the regex (I edited again, sorry)

Comment: If you want check if line start with pattern, you need to add ^ at the start of each line of $itemsFile. You can use `sed -i 's/^/\^/g' $itemsFile`. Be careful, this command change your file.

Comment: @Kintaro Why do you need to check it line by line? This is already what `grep` does.

Answer (score 1):

There are two errors in your script:

- grep tries to match the string `$itemToFind` because you put it between single quote `'`. Use double-quote instead.
- you are using an array from index 1 while `help read` tells it is starting at zero.

This should give this:

```
while IFS=$';' read -r -a array
do
    mapfile -t arrayItems < $itemsFile
    ## now loop through the above array
    for itemToFind in "${arrayItems[@]}"
    do
       itemFound=""
       itemFound=$(echo ${array[0]} | grep -o "$itemToFind")
       if [ -n "$itemFound" ] 
       then 
          echo $itemFound 
          # so end to search in case the item is found
          break
       fi
    done
done < $file_in
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to make it faster, you can use extended regular expressions :

```
grep -E 'apple|sony|samsung' $file_in
```

And if you want to display only brands:

```
grep -E 'apple|sony|samsung' $file_in | awk '{print $1}'
```

Comment: I use ${array[1]} because in the ${array[1]} doesn't contain the data I need from the CSV. ${array[0]} contain the first item of the column (which in this case is a reference code), I need the second item (which is the item name). 

Plus, the first while do other things during every loop (I'm going to add some code in the question)

Comment: I suggest you to add the line `echo array0=${array[0]} array1=${array[1]}` in your loop and check what happens (to me, `${array[0]}` is the complete line, as `read` separates entries with newline characters)

Comment: `$file_in` is a CSV with `;` as a separator (as you can see the 1st while have: `IFS=$';'`), `${array[0]}` contains the first value of the line, `${array[1]}` the 2nd and so no. p.s. I just edited the question code.

Comment: @Kintaro Did changing the single-quote help ?

Comment: yes double quotes helped but then I switched to the -f option